# IConfiguration.GetSection with Where selector

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-3.1, c#-8.0

I'm using [IConfiguration.GetSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration.getsection?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration.GetSection);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to retrieve configuration information from a config file:

```
var loggingProviders = Config.GetSection( "Logging" ).Get<LoggingProviders>();
```

which works just fine, but I want to only retrieve entries that are enabled, so I want to do either of these:

```
var loggingProviders = Config.GetSection( "Logging" ).Get<LoggingProviders>().Where( x => x.Enabled == true );

var loggingProviders = Config.GetSection( "Logging" ).Where( x => x.Enabled == true ).Get<LoggingProviders>();
```

But I keep getting hitting a dead end, any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Show what the section(s) look like in the settings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `.Where`,it needs to be a list,here is a demo:

```
public class LoggingProviders
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    }
```

appsettings.json:

```
"Logging1": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "Enabled": "true"
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "Enabled": "true"
    },
    {
      "Id": "3",
      "Enabled": "false"
    }
  ]
```

startup:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
...
List<LoggingProviders> loggingProviders = Configuration.GetSection("Logging1").Get<List<LoggingProviders>>().Where(x => x.Enabled == true).ToList();
```

result:
[image]

If you don't get a list,and want to use `.where`,you can try to change it to list first.Here is a demo.
appsettings.json:

```
"Logging1": 
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "Enabled": "true"
    },
```

startup:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    ...
List<LoggingProviders> l= new List<LoggingProviders>();
l.Add(Configuration.GetSection("Logging1").Get<LoggingProviders>());
List<LoggingProviders> loggingProviders = l.Where(x => x.Enabled == true).ToList();
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Ah-ha! The Get<List<>> was the missing link, I knew it had to be an enumerable list but I just couldn't figure out how to get there, so obvious now. Much appreciated!